# Is there a way to sort grep output of a csv file?

Tags: grep, sort, csv

I've got a csv file which I need to search in. The problem is that there's too much data in it and looking through the output is kind of problematic. It looks like this

```
col1,col2,...col23
1,123,...,12.01
43,1123,...,142.455
12,63,...,723.1122
...
```

So, after applying some `grep` pattern to it I'd like to have the output sorted by the `col23` in descending order. `col23` contains floating point numbers. Is there a way to do that?

I mean something like this:

```
grep "pattern" the_file.csv | ...sort it
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
grep "pattern" the_file.csv | sort -t, -nk 23 | column -ts,
```

or

```
grep "pattern" the_file.csv | sed 's/,/ /g' | sort -nk 23 | column -t
```

with exponential notation use `sort -g` instead of `sort -n`

Explanation:

- `sort -k 23`: sort on column number 23
- `sort -n`: compare according to string numerical value
- `sort -g`: compare according to general numerical value
- `sort -t,`: sort with delimiter `,`
- `column -t`: make columns based on whitespaces or using delimiter (`-s<delimiter>`)
- `sed 's/,/ /g'`: substitute (`s`) any occurences of `,` with a space `' '` on all lines (`g`)

Comment: That's some magic. It works. Thanks much. Can't you give a little explanation?

Comment: Thank you. BTW, what if some numbers in the column have exponential format? Like 1.231231235E8?

Comment: @St.Antario you're welcome. See my updated answer.